# Separable Space satisfying the Parseval Equation

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working on a question right now that goes as follows:

Prove that a Euclidean space $L$ with scalar product $(x,y)$ is separable if it contains an orthogonal system {$\phi_k$}  such that for any $f \in L$ the Parceval Equation

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty c_k = \|f\|^2$

holds where $c_k = (f, \phi_k)$

I've been stuck with this question trying to relate how to find a countable dense subset from the equation that it needs to satisfy. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ummm interesting, normally questions like these involving Parseval's eq being with assumption of separability, I am curious to see a proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty c_k = \|f\|^2$ is not Parceval's equation !

Parceval's equation: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty |c_k|^2 = \|f\|^2$.

For $n \in \mathbb N$ we have (with $c_k = (f, \phi_k)$):

$||f- \sum_{k=1}^nc_k \phi_k||=||f||^2-\sum_{k=1}^n|c_k|^2 $ (Bessel's equation).

Hence:

$||f||^2=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|c_k|^2 $  for all $f \in L$

$ \iff$

$f= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k \phi_k$ for all $f \in L$

$ \iff$

$\{\phi_k : k \in \mathbb N\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L$.